# Google Data Studio - Extract text after character ? using regex

Tags: looker-studio

I am trying to create a calculated field in Data Studio using regex formula. I would like to extract text after a character ? in the page url. Below is the data input and the expected output

| Input | Output |
| --- | --- |
| example.com/solutions?search=reg | search=reg |
| example.com/solutions?sort_field_name=visits_count&sort_direction=desc&category=Advanced+Patient+Scheduling | sort_field_name=visits_count&sort_direction=desc&category=Advanced+Patient+Scheduling |
| example.com/categories/c2a3dd33-4b3d-4a01-955f-faee81abc871?tab=resources | tab=resources |
| example.com/solutions | null |

I tried following and can't seem to get it to work in Data Studio. But this works here: https://regex101.com/r/k5CRjN/1

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Full page URL,'[^?]+$')
```

I also tried escaping special character but still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

can you try:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT([FIELD NAME],'\\?(.*)$')
```

[image]